# Angular MFE with shared features

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, micro-frontend

I am working on a Angular 11 project that has Micro front end architecture. My portal has multiple applications that has been developed as MFE. I do have lot of common design components such as forms, tables and dashboard etc.what is the best way of implementation to keep those components as reusable across MFE?

Comment: Are you using module federation or anything else to do Micro-Frontend?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MFE with `@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack`
you could make a shared library (I mostly use NX mono repo). Example config:

```
const sharedMappings = new SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(tsConfigPath, ['@xxx/shared-components'], workspaceRootPath);

// inside your module.export //
 new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: 'xxx',
  filename: 'xxx',
  exposes: {
    './Login': 'apps/frontend/auth/src/app/modules/login/login.module.ts'
  },
  shared: share({
    '@angular/core': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
    '@angular/common': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
    '@angular/common/http': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
    '@angular/router': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
    ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors(),
  }),
```

you could find more info regarding this:
[module federation plugin](https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/blob/main/libs/mf/README.md)

Comment: Thanks. Apologies for the delay response. I'm using single-spa with system js